# Auto Increment Field in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a table in a django app where one of the fields is called Order (as in sort order) and is an integer. Every time a new record is entered the field auto increments itself to the next number. My issue is when a record is deleted I would like the other records to shift a number up and cant find anything that would recalculate all the records in the table and shift them a number up if a record is deleted.

For instance there are 5 records in the table where order numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Someone deleted record number 2 and now I would like numbers 3, 4, and 5 to move up to take the deleted number 2's place so the order numbers would now be 1, 2, 3, and 4. Is it possible with python, postgres and django?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why would you want this? This could drastically affect foreign keys...

Comment: @McKay I already answered below that this table is not related to any other tables. Where did the fk came from?

Comment: Oh, I found this question doing a search for IDs, and you're not looking for IDs.

Comment: The question I would have then is "Why on earth do you want this?" It seems like [the `row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what I ended up using:

```
item.delete()
items = table.objects.order_by('order')
count =0
for element in items:
  element.order = count
  element.save()
  count=count+1
```

Answer (score 4):

You are going to have to implement that feature yourself, I doubt very much that a relational db will do that for you, and for good reason: it means updating a potentially large number of rows when one row is deleted.

Are you sure you need this?  It could become expensive.

Comment: This table is a very small table with less than 10 rows and the field is not related to any other tables. Its function is to provide sorting  for the drop down list.

Comment: If it's just for sorting, why do you care if it's totally sequential? A sequence with missing items sorts just as well.

Comment: Because I m showing this number in the list on the screen and dont want missing numbers showing on the screen. Also, when editing I m showing all the records and users will have the ability to change texts but the order numbers will not change.

Comment: But that's just presentation. You can use `{{ forloop.counter }}` for example to show sequential numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off leaving the values in the table alone and using a query to generate the numbering. You can use window functions to do this if you're up to writing some SQL.

```
SELECT
   output_column,
   ...,
   row_number() over (
     order by
       order_column)
FROM
  TheTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting orders - you should create a field which is a boolean (call it whatever you like - for example, `deleted`) and set this field to `1` for "deleted" orders.

Messing with a serial field (which is what your auto-increment field is called in postgres) will lead to problems later; especially if you have foreign keys and relationships with tables.

Not only will it impact your database server's performance; it also will impact on your business as eventually you will have two orders floating around that have the same order number; even though you have "deleted" one from the database, the order number may already be referenced somewhere else - like in a receipt your printed for your customer.

Comment: Like I commented on the other answer.  This field is just for sorting the dropdown list. Its not related to any other table and I would like it to be clean without missing any sequence numbers in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signals/) post_save and post_delete to query the appropriate objects, sort them, and then look for missing numbers and reassign/save as necessary. This might be pretty heavy for a lot of data, but for only a few items that change rarely, it would be ok.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

def fix_order(sorted_objects):
    #ensures that the given objects have sequential order values from 1 upwards
    i = 1
    for item in sorted_objects
        if item.order != i:
            item.order = i
            item.save()
        i += 1

@receiver(post_delete, sender=YourSortedModel)
def update_order_post_delete(sender, kwargs):
    #get the sorted items you need
    sort_items = YourSortedModel.objects.filter(....).order_by('order')
    fix_order(sort_items)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this looking for something else and wanted to point something out:

By storing the order in a field in the same table as your data, you lose data integrity, or if you index it things will get very complicated if you hit a conflict.  In other words, it's very easy to have a bug (or something else) give you two 3's, a missing 4, and other weird things can happen.  I inherited a project with a manual sort order that was critical to the application (there were other issues as well) and this was constantly an issue, with just 200-300 items.

The right way to handle a manual sort order is to have a separate table to manage it and sort with a join.  This way your Order table will have exactly 10 entries with just it's PK (the order number) and a foreign key relationship to the ID of the items you want to sort.  Deleted items just won't have a reference anymore.

You can continue to sort on delete similar to how you're doing it now, you'll just be updating the Order model's FK to list instead of iterating through and re-writing all your items.  Much more efficient.

This will scale up to millions of manually sorted items easily.  But rather than using auto-incremented ints, you would want to give each item a random order id in between the two items you want to place it between and keep plenty of space (few hundred thousand should do it) so you can arbitrarily re-sort them.

I see you mentioned that you've only got 10 rows here, but designing your architecture to scale well the first time, as a practice, will save you headaches down the road, and once you're in the habit of it, it won't really take you any more time.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the value with type `sequence` in postgres using pgadmin.

Comment: Thanks. Would that shift the numbers up when one of them is deleted?

Comment: mmmm... no, that's not autoincremental